# secure gateway ACL_FILE definition?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, dataworks, dataconnect

My /etc/ibm/sgenvironment.conf file has a ACL_FILE:

```
# Access Control List File
# If manually modifying the following, accepted values are the absolute path to your ACL files ('none' if no file, separated by '--' otherwise)
ACL_FILE=/home/snowch/securegateway_acl
```

What is the format of the ACL_FILE?  Where can I find documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here in the end:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_010.html#sg_015

I'm adding an answer because I think it will be useful to other users:

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find documentation in the readme that comes with the client, as well as a sample ACL file.  Check `/opt/ibm/securegateway/docs` for the readme and check `/opt/ibm/securegateway/client` for the sample ACL file.